# Updating the webpage using Flask based on MySQL database.

Tags: python, mysql, client-server, flask, html

I have a webpage (built using HTML & jQuery) which displays the data from a MySQL database. I am using Flask to connect HTML with my database. However, my database gets updated every 15 minutes (using a separate Python Script). Currently, I stop the flask server, update the database and restart the Flask to update the webpage. My question is the following:

Is there a way to update the MySQL database in the background without having to stop the flask server? I read about concepts of AJAX and CRON, however i am not able to understand how to use them with flask asynchronously.

Note: I am a newbie in web applications and this is my first project which involves connecting client side and server side. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you don't stop the Flask server, what error do you get?

Comment: You say your database is updated every 15 minutes, then ask is there a wa to update the MySQL database in the background. As far as I can tell, that is what you're already doing with that separate python script. I really don't understand what you're asking here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are most likely doing something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from yourMySqlLibrary import connect_to_mysql

conn = connect_to_mysql()
# This is only executed when you start the script
data = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM MySemiRegularlyUpdatedTable")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def view_data():
    return render_template("view_data.html", data=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

If that is the case, then your solution is simply to move your connection and query calls *into* your controller so that the database is re-queried every time you hit the page:

```
@app.route("/")
def view_data():
    # Removed from above and placed here
    # The connection is made to the database for each request
    conn = connect_to_mysql()
    # This is only executed on every request
    data = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM MySemiRegularlyUpdatedTable")
    return render_template("view_data.html", data=data)
```

This way, your view will update when your data does - and you won't have to restart the server just to pick up changes to your data.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i was looking for. I was not connecting to my database from inside the controller. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could you please answer this question using jquery Ajax and a refresh interval of ??? 5 minutes. TIA. I think so the view updates from the browser.....

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but at what scope the objects initiated outside the controller live? Initialized only the first time the app is launched? Persisting across requests?